# Positive semidefiniteness of symmetric matrix

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization

I have a question regarding the positive semidefiniteness (PSD) of a symmetric matrix. I have seen different conditions stated in papers and journals, and I end wondering which are correct.
Three definitions I have seen:
1) A symmetric matrix is PSD if and only if all its principal minors are non-
negative.
2) A symmetric matrix is PSD if and only if the sum of the principal minors of order k (for each k) are non-negative.
3) A symmetric matrix is PSD if and only if the leading principal minors are non-negative.

Those conditions do not seem equivalent to me (1 => 2 but not the converse for example. Can somebody provide guidance / references? I have found the above definitions in reputable books or journals.

Comment: Neither of this is the definition, which should be the quadratic form is nonnegative. I recommend Carl Meyer's book as a reference for this.

Comment: § 3.2 of https://www.math.univ-toulouse.fr/~jbhu/SDP-HU-Malick-2012pdf.pdf covers all three of these, and has some references.